Is there a standard way to quantify & test the benefit to one covariate by including a second covariate?
For a linear model (or glm), is there a standard statistic (and associated test) to quantify whether inclusion of a covariate increases the strength of the association between another covariate and the dependent variable?
Example, I have two models:

Y ~ X1
Y ~ X1 + X2

I know I can e.g. use a likelihood ratio test to evaluate whether model 2 is better at explaining Y, but this could be driven entirely by the independent contribution of X2. Is there a "test" (or even just an interpretable statistic) to measure whether X1 gets significantly (or meaningfully) better at explaining Y, given X2?

Partial R-squared is a standardized metric to compare the relative importance of X1 and X2 in explaining Y.  You could consider the rsq R package.
Another option is Relative Explained Variation as implemented in rms::rexVar.  A related approach is to divide the partial likelihood ratio test statistic by the overall model likelihood ratio test statistic, for example.

Can these be used to directly compare relative explained variation for the same predictor in two models?

I’m not sure I understand your question. The above methods can be used to assess the relative importance of X1 and X2  in explaining Y.  Alternatively, if you are interested in whether model 1 or 2 is better at explaining Y, then you can use adjusted Rsquared or AIC or BIC to compare the 2 models.
